# What are Pros and Cons in using prefixes and suffixes in PostgreSQL dialect for timestamp columns

Tags: postgresql, datetime, database-design, timestamp

I have analysed several articles about naming conventions for Date/Time types in SQL data models.
Most of them suggest implementing a database design where a `timestamp` type is used for some registered even values only, literally timestamping the event case just when it happens. And naturally they suggest `datetime` type for any other time instanting needs. And they suggest to avoid using suffixes and prefixes which match known data types, like `date` and `time`, at all costs, to avoid confusion with data types where only the purpose of the column name is expected.

But PostgreSQL dialect does not have that `datetime` type at all, so there is only the `timestamp` type for all cases when just `date` and `time` are not enough for the column which is expected to store a value of past or future instant of time.

So, basically, what prefixes or suffixes if any would you suggest for PostgreSQL dialect columns, known that some of them would store past and present and future  time instants? And why, for what benefits or because of what limitations?

Should we use `timestamp` and `datetime` as prefixes or suffixes to distinguish the purpose of different `timestamp` type columns by their names? Or would that be a bad practice since there is actually a data type named `timestamp` and no data type named `datetime` in PostgreSQL dialect?

Or should we maybe use something very neurtal like an `instant` noun as a prefix or suffix to denote the purpose of the column?

Comment: No prefix at all. The column name should document what it contains (e.g. `created_at` or `expires_at`...). Note that there is no `datetime` type in standard SQL anyway. Why do you think that a `datetime` type is something different than a `timestamp`? Those are simply two different names for the same thing

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what would be a generic approach for naming columns to document what it contains when it contains some abstract instant of time? Should not we denote them with an `instant` suffix for example?

Wikipedia says a timestamp is used to identify when an event has already occured. While a datetime identifies any instant of time, even it is a future instant of time.

Comment: My random examples for `timestamp` column names:

`creation_instant` - in the past,

`last_modification_instant` - in the past,

`archiving_instant` - optional and in the past,

`next_upcoming_invoice_instant` - optional and in the future.

Comment: I don't think there is a "generic" approach. You use `creation_instant` where I would prefer `created_at`. Just use a name where everybody in your project understands what it is. Don't bother thinking about prefixes or suffixes. And in the context of SQL "datetime" and "timestamp" are the same thing (with the latter being portable, because it's standard SQL)